# Wordpress: page created and published but not found

Tags: wordpress

I have just setup wordpress and create a page. 
When I click on preview, I get a 404 saying that the resource was not available on the server.

I am using Apache2.2 on windows.

Cheers,
Earlence

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your permalink structure - set it to default and try again. Has this worked before on this server, or is this your first time trying?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the permalinks. If you have changed them, it's either you [are missing the .htaccess file](http://www.squidoo.com/wordpress-not-found-error-fix) or you don't have mod_rewrite enabled for Apache2. You can search how to do that on Windows on your own! Cheers! :)